# Rich-Rule Invalid_Rule: Destination action

Tags: centos7, firewalld

I am trying to add a rich rule to isolate a dev environment for a contractor to develop on.
I have placed the machine on a DMZ, but i would like to isolate it a little further, and from the OS level.

Running CentOS 7.1.1503 firewalld 0.3.9-11

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address='192.168.1.225' destination address='192.168.1.222' drop"
```

I receive the error

```
Error: INVALID_RULE: destination action
```

Which appears to be a catch-all error.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but it's a bug within `firewalld`
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1326462

You will get this error when you use both source and destination address but no protocol/port.

Fixed in firewalld-0.4.2-1.el7